# Angular2 Routing with parameters fails

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-component-router

I am having troubles (all sorts of errors in very unexpected places) and my best guess is that it happens because of the way routing is set up.

This is my **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'calendar/:urlString', component: CalendarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'myprofile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'profiles', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'locations', component: LocationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

Then, in **CalendarComponent.ts** I have this piece of code:

```
 imports (...)

 constructor(
   private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
 ){
 }

 public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.resolveURLParams(params);
    });
  }

  public resolveURLParams( params ): void {

    // do stuff based on params

  }
```

Anyway, just a half year ago (some RC @Angular2) I could start the app by typing any of these directly into the browser

`localhost:3000`,

`localhost:3000/calendar` or

`localhost:3000/calendar/2017-05-27`

and would get expected results. Now I *have* to start from `localhost:3000`, so that *the app* routes me through `../login` --> `../calendar` --> `../calendar/2017-05-27`, otherwise I get all sorts of troubles, like `Cannot read property subscribe of null` or `Cannot activate already activated outlet`.

I guess, the routing has been updated and I am lagging behind. Any help on this, please?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to actually list the errors you're seeing.

Comment: If I start from `/calendar`, I get **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet**. If I start from `/calendar/2017-05` I get **Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null** at resolveUrlParams function

Comment: Mhm, i cannot reproduce your kind of error. Can you provide a runnable plnkr sample?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a time delay in subscribing to the route params, I suggest you to use non-Observable option using the service ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Inject the service `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and get the params using

```
this.activatedRoute.route.snapshot.params.urlString
```

Note: use `pathMatch:full` for the definition

```
{ path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] , pathMatch:'full'},
```

as your route will fall through in the order of definition and tries to match the param one with the above

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bummer, but there was *no problem* with the way routes and ActivatedRoute subscription worked. The problem was with the AuthGuard I was using, which was broken. Now that I've fixed the guard, all the problems went away. So, thanks for trying to help.