# Angular 2 get value from url with promise and await

Tags: angular, typescript

So i'm trying to get the the value from the url and i want to do this with promise and async/await. But when i run this in both chrome and opera it just stands and wait on that point. 
Anyone got that can point me in the right direction or am i doing something wrong ?

My component implements : implements OnInit

Constructor :

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private zone : NgZone
            ) 
            {

            }
```

The imports :

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Methods:

```
async ngOnInit() 
{
    var Id : string = await this.getIdFromUrl(); 
}


getIdFromUrl() : Promise<string> 
    {
        return this.route.params.map(params => 
        {   
            return params['id']; 
        }).toPromise();  
    }
```

Comment: Have a look into [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221485/angular2-routing-with-parameters-fails/44221712#44221712)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is supposed to return `void`. Making it `async` indicates XY problem, this [deviates from the interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html) because async `ngOnInit` returns a promise and results in potentially uncaught promise errors. If there are promises that should be resolved on initialization, they can be made resolvers.

`route.params` is an observable because it emits multiple values when navigating to the same route with different params. It isn't completed and calling `toPromise()` on it will result in pending promise. For this reason observables aren't interchangeable with promises.

Initial param value is already known on component initialization and is synchronous. It is reachable with [`ActivatedRouteSnapshot` interface](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html),

```
ngOnInit() {
    const id: string = route.snapshot.params.id;
}
```

Depending on how a route is used and [route reuse strategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html), this may not work as expected, because subsequent param changes won't be handled. It is generally preferable to stick to `route.params` observable for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it fixed a lot :)

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. `const syncRoute: any = this._route.snapshot; ` shows no params, I have to listen to them asynchronously with `this._route.queryParamMap.subscribe(parameter => {.. ` and therefore have massive racing conditions in my ngOnInit() . The URL is simply called, no changing values in it whatsoever.

Comment: @NikitaFuchs This depends on your case. There can be scenarios when a param won't be available on component init. See the remark, *Depending on how a route is used and route reuse strategy, this may not work as expected, because subsequent param changes won't be handled*.